# (Discord.js) get channel by it's name

Tags: discord.js

So basically my goal is to get a specific channel by it's name. I want to store it in a variable so I can delete it later.

```
let channel = //store specific channel in this variable using its name// ;
channel.delete();
```

And yes, I know I should use its ID because it's better, but in this case I can't use it's ID, I have to use its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GuildChannelManager#find()`

```
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'channel-name-here');

channel.delete();
```